# Reading Microsoft Access Database 64bit

Tags: c#, ms-access, 64-bit

I have a situation where I'm moving my .NET application to 64bit and I still need to read data from an Microsoft Access database from within C# code. I've had a suggestion where I could write a web service that reads the data periodically from the Microsoft Access and dumps it into SQL Server, so I could then read from SQL table in my application rather than accessing the Microsoft Access database directly.

This has issues like reading from the Microsoft Access database on a specific PC from the web service or WCF service. But I guess an account with relevant permissions would resolve this.

Has anyone else had a situation like this? If so, how have you worked around it?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Just out of curiousity... why not tranfer everything over to the SQL Server database and dump Access entirely? I ran into an issue a couple months ago when we tried to build a web app that used the data in Access. It was such a mess we just decided to migrate all the data to Oracle and scrap Access.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Microsoft Access database is part of a 3rd party package that my application has to read data from. It is out of my hands I'm afraid. That is what I'd like to do though :)

Comment: Ah, yeah. I am certainly fortunate that I had the ability to just move on to another solution. Access is a HUGE pain to try and get to play nice with other programs. Best of luck.

Comment: The old version of the ACE OleDB provider and the JET provider do not support and cannot support x64 since they are both 32-bit.  The only solution is to use the Office 2010 ACE OleDb provider as linked HansUp.  I should point out this provider is not meant to be used by a system service, it never was, none of the solutions were meant to do this.

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to link the Access DB to the SQL Server. See [Linking Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the ACE OleDb provider to connect your .Net application to Access?

It's a free download, available in both 32 and 64 bit versions.  [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you also need to read xlsx in 32-bit application in 64-bit windows, Install MADE 2007 instead of MADE 2010(x86), because same version of MADE 2010(x86 + x64) cannot coexist.