# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered in local system

Tags: asp.net

I import excel file into database from my below connection string of .net code.

When i run it from 64-bit server 2008 PC it runs from visual studio 2005 properly, but when i

publish code and run it from IIS, virtual directory it gives error.

Comment: 64-bit use another name and version for this, Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990537/reading-microsoft-access-database-64bit/9407406#9407406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following,

- Install Microsoft Access Database Engine.exe.
- On IIS goto Application pools, choose the application pool of the website.
- Click on Advanced settings, set Enable 32-bit Applications to true.everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Micorsoft Access Database Engine. Please download relevant verions and install.

```
[ Micorsoft Access Database Engine][1]
```

Comment: yes, i have already installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe. But same problem occured.